# greyed out link in outlet list of Connections Inspector

Tags: xcode, storyboard

In the image below look on the right side in the "Outlets" section; the connection is from `view` to `View` and it is greyed out. I cannot delete it or alter it. I only saw this anomaly
while trying to figure out why the UIButton named `Button` is never activated. You can see that `Button` is hooked up in the bottom of the Connections Inspector. 
[image: Xcode storyboard window]

Code for the `Button` is below.

```
- (IBAction)startPause
{
    NSLog(@"startPause: %d %d:", cardNum,self.randCut);
    if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
        timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(dealCard) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        card.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",cardNum];
        [timer fire];
    }
}
```

Is there any likelihood that the two anomalies (greyed connection and dead button) are related, and can you help fix either or both, please?

Comment: The view is a default view of the view controller which can't be altered, so it is normal to be greyed out. For the button, can it be tapped in the first place? Is the NSLog logging the startPause message"

Comment: No, the NSLog is NOT logging the startPause message. That is very frustrating. Can I sort of reset everything without losing it? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Wait.  Now I see that NO button on that View is active. They all ignore taps. What's up?

Comment: Maybe there is a view blocking them

Comment: I think the problem was the correct segue for my prepareForSegue was not id'd, or maybe I had copy/pasted another VC to create this bad one and some of the old links were retained but hidden from me. Anyhow, thanks for everyone's help. I rebuilt the VC from scratch and all is well.